# Drop temp table within IF ELSE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am facing a deadlock here, the issue is that I have to alter a procedure which makes use of 3 different temp tables. Lets for the sake of the conversation name them #temptable1, #temptable2, #temptable3.
I cannot copy/paste the whole procedure here but the general idea is this, The original procedure (procedure1) creates the #temptable1 at the very beginning of the process

```
create table #temptable1
```

then creates the remaining two by using a select/into statement

```
select  T.Col
    ,   T.Col2
    ,   T.Col3
into   #temptable2
from   table1 T
where  T.BB>0

select  T.Col
    ,   T.Col2
    ,   T.Col3
into   #temptable3
from   table2 T
where  T.BB>0

drop table #temptable1
drop table #temptable2
drop table #temptable3
```

Until this point it works fine, but what I want to do is to alter the procedure by adding an if/else statement. Thus to look like that,

```
declare @BBB nvarchar(32)

create table #temptable1


if @BBB='dd'

begin 

select  T.Col
        ,   T.Col2
        ,   T.Col3
    into   #temptable2
    from   table1 T
    where  T.BB>0 and T.G='FDL'

    select  T.Col
        ,   T.Col2
        ,   T.Col3
    into   #temptable3
    from   table2 T
    where  T.BB>0 and T.G='FDL'

    drop table #temptable1
    drop table #temptable2
    drop table #temptable3
end 

if @BBB='kk'

begin 

select  T.Col
        ,   T.Col2
        ,   T.Col3
    into   #temptable2
    from   table1 T
    where  T.BB>0 and T.G='FD'

    select  T.Col
        ,   T.Col2
        ,   T.Col3
    into   #temptable3
    from   table2 T
    where  T.BB>0 and T.G='FD'

    drop table #temptable1
    drop table #temptable2
    drop table #temptable3
end

else 

begin 

select  T.Col
        ,   T.Col2
        ,   T.Col3
    into   #temptable2
    from   table1 T
    where  T.BB>0

    select  T.Col
        ,   T.Col2
        ,   T.Col3
    into   #temptable3
    from   table2 T
    where  T.BB>0

    drop table #temptable1
    drop table #temptable2
    drop table #temptable3
end
```

When I try to create the new procedure I get this message,

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pPortfoliostest3, Line 412
There is already an object named '#temptable1' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pPortfoliostest3, Line 550
There is already an object named '#temptable2' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pPortfoliostest3, Line 711
There is already an object named '#temptable3' in the database.
```

The lines are indicating where the temp tables are within the second if statement (if @BBB='kk').
I have tried different combinations but to no avail. Any tips? Thank you for your time.

Comment: try putting those `drop table statements at the beginning of the code`

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: nop, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The T-SQL parser is remarkably primitive. In particular, *control* flow doesn't affect when object names come into scope and remain in scope.

So the names you're using in your `if` branch are still in scope and cause a conflict when the `else` branch is parsed.

If possible, move the table definitions up to the top of the stored procedure, before any control flow, and switch to `INSERT ... SELECT ...` rather than `SELECT ... INTO ...`; or if the table definitions don't match between the `if` and `else` branches, you'll need to use different names for the temp tables.

---

As another example of how primitive the parser is, consider the following:

```
if 1=0
begin
    declare @a int
end
select @a
```

This produces a result set containing `null` rather than (as you might have expected) an error saying that `@a` isn't declared.