# error in IF ELSE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, runtime-error

I have the following stored procedure, But seems like the `#Temp` table is creating troubles in it. I get following error

> There is already an object named '#Temp' in the database.

I guess somethings wrong with my IF ELSE

Here is the stored procedure:

```
create procedure spGetHOSalesReport
@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@EmbossLine varchar(20),@CountryID int,@status char(2)     

AS    

Set @DateTo = @DateTo +1    

if(@status = 'E1')
begin

    Select PT.[ID] 'TransactionID', PT.BatchNumber, PT.SequenceNumber, PT.TransactionDate, 
    PT.TerminalID, PT.TotalAmount, PT.TransactionTypeID, TT.TransactionType,PT.PAN 'EmbossLine',PT.PreBalanceAmount, PT.PostBalanceAmount, RefTxnID, SettlementDate,PaidCash, CreditAmount, DiscountAmount,    
    RefPAN, PT.Remarks, '&nbsp; ' + CashierCard as 'SupervisorCard',St.StoreID    
    into #Temp    
    from TempPOS_Transactions PT inner join TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID     
    inner join Staff St on St.CardNumber=PT.CashierCard     

    where     

    PT.[ID] not in (Select distinct isnull(TransactionID,0) from Testcards)          
    and (PT.TransactionDate >= @DateFrom) and (PT.TransactionDate < @DateTo)    
    and (PT.TransactionTypeID = 6) and (PT.BatchNumber = 0) and (Pt.SequenceNumber =-1) 



    select T.*, '&nbsp; '+  C.EmbossLine+'&nbsp;' as 'EmbossLine',  C.EmbossLine as 'EmbossLine1',    
    isnull(C.FirstName,'') +' '+ isnull(C.LastName,'') 'EmbossName',C.FirstName,C.LastName,City.CityName,Country.CountryName,Country.CurrencyName, PM.MerchantID, PM.MerchantName1, C.AccountNumber, C.VehicleNumber, C.ExpiryDate ,
    case C.Status when 'E0' then 'Authorized' when 'E1' then 'Pending' end 'Status'   

    from #Temp T     

    inner join Card C on C.EmbossLine= T.EmbossLine    
    inner join Terminal on Terminal.TerminalID = T.TerminalID    
    inner join Merchant PM on  PM.MerchantID = Terminal.MerchantID    
    inner join City on City.CityID = PM.CityID    
    inner join Country on Country.CountryID = PM.CountryID     
    where C.Status <>'E3'    

    and C.CardID not in (Select distinct isnull(CardID,0) from Testcards)    

    and (C.EmbossLine like '%'+@EmbossLine+'%' or @EmbossLine like '-999')      
    and (PM.CountryID = @CountryID or @CountryID ='-999')    

    and (C.Status = @status)    

   order by T.TransactionDate, MerchantName1, T.BatchNumber, T.SequenceNumber    

End

Else
Begin

    Select PT.[ID] 'TransactionID', PT.BatchNumber, PT.SequenceNumber, PT.TransactionDate, 
    PT.TerminalID, PT.TotalAmount, PT.TransactionTypeID, TT.TransactionType,PT.PAN 'EmbossLine',PT.PreBalanceAmount, PT.PostBalanceAmount, RefTxnID, SettlementDate,PaidCash, CreditAmount, DiscountAmount,    
    RefPAN, PT.Remarks, '&nbsp; ' + CashierCard as 'SupervisorCard',St.StoreID    
    into #Temp    
    from POS_Transactions PT inner join TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID     
    inner join Staff St on St.CardNumber=PT.CashierCard     

    where PT.[ID] not in (Select distinct isnull(TransactionID,0) from Testcards) and (PT.TransactionDate >= @DateFrom) and (PT.TransactionDate < @DateTo)    
    and (PT.TransactionTypeID = 6) and (PT.BatchNumber = 0) and (Pt.SequenceNumber =-1) 

    select T.*, '&nbsp; '+  C.EmbossLine+'&nbsp;' as 'EmbossLine',  C.EmbossLine as 'EmbossLine1',    
    isnull(C.FirstName,'') +' '+ isnull(C.LastName,'') 'EmbossName',C.FirstName,C.LastName,City.CityName,Country.CountryName,Country.CurrencyName, PM.MerchantID, PM.MerchantName1, C.AccountNumber, C.VehicleNumber, C.ExpiryDate ,
    case C.Status when 'E0' then 'Authorized' when 'E1' then 'Pending' end 'Status'   

    from #Temp T     

    inner join Card C on C.EmbossLine= T.EmbossLine    
    inner join Terminal on Terminal.TerminalID = T.TerminalID    
    inner join Merchant PM on  PM.MerchantID = Terminal.MerchantID    
    inner join City on City.CityID = PM.CityID    
    inner join Country on Country.CountryID = PM.CountryID     
    where C.Status <>'E3'    

    and C.CardID not in (Select distinct isnull(CardID,0) from Testcards)    

    and (C.EmbossLine like '%'+@EmbossLine+'%' or @EmbossLine like '-999')      
    and (PM.CountryID = @CountryID or @CountryID ='-999')    

    and (C.Status = @status)    

   order by T.TransactionDate, MerchantName1, T.BatchNumber, T.SequenceNumber    
End 


  drop table #Temp
```

Comment: Sorry was a Typo. Edited

Comment: Ok, I see that you changed an error. Try to use the answer below

Comment: Not an issue with your `IF/ELSE` statement, just SQL Server's primitive parser.

Comment: @GarethD How do I resolve it?

Comment: @Nuke Read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23779924/1048425) in the duplicate question.

Comment: @GarethD Can you please help me write a `Insert into` ? I am not familiar with its syntax.

Comment: You could probably get away with using two different temp tables. Ie keep your current syntax, but rename the second #temp table to f.ex. #temp2 and move/copy the drop to both if and else.

Comment: Instead of `SELECT A, B, C INTO #Temp FROM T`, You need to first create the temp table - `CREATE TABLE #Temp (A INT, B VARCHAR(10), C INT)`, then you can insert to it - `INSERT #Temp (A, B, C) SELECT A, B, C FROM T;`

Comment: Or better yet, replace the use of #Temp table with a subquery / CTE? I don't really see the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two statements in the same procedure that creates a temp table with the same name. This is a leftover from SQL 6.5 which did not have deferred name resolution.

And in any case, it only makes sense if the tables are created exactly the same, else your procedure will behave very funky.

So instead of using `SELECT INTO`, use `CREATE TABLE + INSERT`.

**UPDATE**

According to the selected way from comment:

> Second option: First create temp table and insert

First let's create the temp table. For that you should modify your procedure like:

```
create procedure spGetHOSalesReport
@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@EmbossLine varchar(20),@CountryID int,@status char(2)
AS    
BEGIN -- begin procedure
  SET @DateTo = @DateTo +1

  if object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null drop table #Temp
  create table #Temp
  ( TransactionID int
  , BatchNumber ... ( your type of field )
  , SequenceNumber ...
  , TransactionDate ...
  , TerminalID int
  , TotalAmount ...
  , TransactionTypeID int
  , TransactionType ...
  , EmbossLine ...
  , PreBalanceAmount ...
  , PostBalanceAmount ...
  , RefTxnID int
  , SettlementDate ...
  , PaidCash ...
  , CreditAmount ...
  , DiscountAmount ...
  , RefPAN ...
  , Remarks ...
  , SupervisorCard ...
  , StoreID int
  )
  if(@status = 'E1')
  .......
```

I do not know which data type has these fields, so, you have to do yourself.
 Then edit insert into temp table in first case and similar in another case:

```
    insert into #Temp
    Select PT.[ID] 'TransactionID', PT.BatchNumber, PT.SequenceNumber, PT.TransactionDate, 
    PT.TerminalID, PT.TotalAmount, PT.TransactionTypeID, TT.TransactionType,PT.PAN 'EmbossLine',PT.PreBalanceAmount, PT.PostBalanceAmount, RefTxnID, SettlementDate,PaidCash, CreditAmount, DiscountAmount,    
    RefPAN, PT.Remarks, '&nbsp; ' + CashierCard as 'SupervisorCard',St.StoreID    
    from TempPOS_Transactions PT inner join TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID     
    inner join Staff St on St.CardNumber=PT.CashierCard     
    where ...
```

In the end of procedure you can add:

```
End -- end of your if
if object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null drop table #Temp
END -- end of procedure
```

But the simplest way is create two different temp tables:

```
if(@status = 'E1')
begin        
  if object_id('tempdb..#Temp1') is not null drop table #Temp1
  Select PT.[ID] 'TransactionID', PT.BatchNumber, ...   
  into #Temp1    
  from TempPOS_Transactions PT 
  inner join TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID             
  .....     
end
else 
begin
  if object_id('tempdb..#Temp2') is not null drop table #Temp2
  Select PT.[ID] 'TransactionID', PT.BatchNumber, ...
  into #Temp2    
  from POS_Transactions PT 
  inner join TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID           
  ....
end
```

Also, you can write just two `select` without creating temp table in this case

Comment: I did. Still getting the same error

Comment: Where did you add this check?

Comment: right before `if(@status = 'E1')` and after `Set @DateTo = @DateTo +1`

Comment: Can you please explain it by editing my code?

Comment: Anything that would work

Comment: Please select: 1. two different temp table 2.first create the temp table and insert 3.subquery / CTE

Comment: Second option: First create temp table and insert