# Temp table parsing - SQL bug - Explanation needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have the following code that cannot be executed. I am not looking for work-around. I want to understand what is SQL doing and why it is failing with error: 'There is already an object named '#t' in the database.' Please care to explain.

```sql
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#t') is not null

drop table #t

GO

declare @i int = 0

if @i = 0

create table #t (col1 int)

else

create table #t (col1 int)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the [tag:sql] tag and a tag for the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: ty Ken. I just did

Comment: Is this the exact script you're trying to execute?

Comment: No. This is a simplification of the full script. Full script makes no sense. Error is the same

Comment: This is a limitation of how compilation works. Conditionally creating temp tables is fraught with peril because the optimizer does need to know whether or not the table is there (and its schema) to generate execution plans for statements referring to it, so `#t` is still considered "the same" table wherever it occurs, and duplicate `CREATE`s are therefore disallowed (as are other incompatible DDL statements). To a first approximation, just don't do this at all. Keep your temp table schemes constant and don't create them conditionally. FWIW, you can conditionally `ALTER` them.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I can think of several workarounds but wanted to understand what is going on. Where is the famous 'deferred name resolution'. SQL will compile correctly if user tables are used ( # is removed). So this is as you said; something going on in TEMPDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
-checking Temp table is exists , if Exists then Drop the table
  IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t

 --Declaring Variable @i and assigning value 0
   DECLARE @i int = 0
  --Checking @i = 0 or not
  IF @i = 0
  BEGIN
      -- if @i value is 0 
      CREATE TABLE #t (col1 int)

  END
  GO
  --checking Temp table is exists , if Exists then Drop the table

   IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
   --Declaring Variable @i and assigning value 1

    DECLARE @i int = 1 --  Checking @i = 1
  IF @i= 1
  BEGIN    
        -- if @i value is not 0 
         CREATE TABLE #t (col1 int)
  END
  GO
```

Comment: Please check your code and try to run. It does not compile. Error is: "There is already an object named '#t' in the database." Same I am getting.

Comment: It's a limitation. Dynamic SQL won't work either since #tmp will be created in a new session and immediately lost.

Comment: So far it is a unwanted compilation behaviour in TEMPDB that results in a bug since error provided by SQL is not right nor true.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use different names for the temp tables.

At least if you really need to create the temp table within the `IF` and the `ELSE`.

Or drop & create the temp table only once at the start, before the `IF`.

Sadly, the compiler gets confused over such a trifling thing.
When the T-Sql is parsed and evaluated, it ignores control flow statements like `IF`.
So the create of the same temporary table is seen in the same scope, and evaluated as a duplicate object problem.

Example of a work-around:

```
declare @i int = 0

if @i = 0
 begin
   if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null
     drop table #t1;
   create table #t1 (col1 int);
 end
else
  begin
    if object_id('tempdb..#t2') is not null
       drop table #t2;
    create table #t2 (col1 int, col2 int);
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Luk. I ended up doing something similar in my code. But was not looking for workaround. Wanted to understand why SQL returns an invalid message and gets a buggy behaviour. So far it is because compiler gets confused and bugged in TEMPDB. does not happen if tables are created in user tables (# is removed)

Comment: Haven't found an official reason for it either.  Just [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23779924/4003419) old SO post.

Comment: Thanks Luk. Yes. Looks like that guy had similar issue. Workarounds are available. Just wanted to understand what was really going on. Appreciated.